# Prove there $\exists n$ such that $ \left|\left\{\{x, y, z\}: x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, x<y<z, x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=n\right\}\right| \geq 2021 $

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinations, sums-of-squares

The Problem is that:

Show that there is a positive integer $ n $ such that
$$
\left|\left\{\{x, y, z\}: x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, x<y<z, x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=n\right\}\right| \geq 2021
$$

I tried to solve it by consider the 3-subset $\in \{1, 2, ..., \sqrt{n}\}$, but calculate the numbers of $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=n$ seems hard to me. Any hints or solutions are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider an $N\gg1$, and let $B$
be the ball of radius $\sqrt{N}$ around the origin.  The part $B_+$ of this ball containing the points with $0<x<y<z$ has volume
$${\rm vol}(B_+)={\pi N^{3/2}\over 36}\ .$$
The number of lattice points $(x,y,z)$ lying in $B_+$ is about equal to this volume (I'm omitting the approximation estimates). All of these lattice points have integer $x^2+y^2+z^2\in[N]$. By the pigeon principle there is then an $n\in[N]$ such that at least $${{\rm vol}(B_+)\over N}={\pi\sqrt{N}\over36}$$
of them  have $x^2+y^2+z^2=n$. Choosing
$$N\geq\left({36\cdot2021\over\pi}\right)^2$$
then proves the claim.

Comment: I may be missing something, but if the volume of $B$ is $\frac{4\pi N^{3/2}}{3}$, then shouldn't the volume of one octant be $\frac{\pi N^{3/2}}{6}$? Why is your denominator $36$?

Comment: @KeithBackman: Because of the condition $x<y<z$.